# How to sort table in protractor using _.sort lodash function

Tags: protractor

I am trying to sort a data table. Here is my code :

```
    let cellsText = [];
    let length = await this.lastActivity.count();
    for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    let text = await this.lastActivity.get(i);
    cellsText.push(text)
    let celltext = await text.getText();
    let sortedCellText = _.sortBy([celltext]);
    expect(sortedCellText).toEqual(celltext);
```

However this fails with the following output:

Expected [ '16 Apr 2018 15:54' ] to equal '16 Apr 2018 15:54'.

How do i get rid of this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could simplify the solution perhaps to the following :

```
let cellText = await Promise.all(_.map([elementfinder], function(elm) {
  return elm.getText();
 }));
 let sortedCellText = _.sort(cellText);
 expect(cellText).toEqual(sortedCellText);
```